# ActionbarSherlock: Long-click on action item show a Toast?

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, toast, long-click

When an action item is long-clicked, a Toast without text is show below the action item. 
Can I disable the `Toast`?
Thanks you.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you omit a title or specify that the action item should be displayed with text then long-pressing will not toast. Otherwise the toast adds clarification of what each action item represents.

Comment: how do you omit the title? `.setTitle(null)` or `.setTitle("")` doesn't work.. how do I "specify that the action item should be displayed with text then long-pressing"?

Comment: This is not working for me too... I have not specified a title in the menu XML file but I still see a (empty) toast when long-pressing an item.

Comment: i guess the answer is accepted for that each item will toast. @Jake is there a way we can omit the title?

Comment: This does not work anymore. On KitKat I still get a toast but empty.

Answer (score 0):

Using this answer to get the action bar view: https://stackoverflow.com/a/21125631/555914
I used this to disable the toast:

```
View actionBar = AppUtils.getActionBarView(getActivity());
        if(actionBar!=null) {
            View item = actionBar.findViewById(id);
            if(item!=null) {
                item.setOnLongClickListener(null);
            }
        }
```

Although I do not recommend disabling this functionality but sometimes designers want something for esthetic reasons...