# Android how to remove title hint from item in action bar

Tags: android, android-actionbar, actionbarsherlock

When user does a long press over a menu item in an action bar, a little hint (Toast style) is showed with the title of the item.

I would like to remove that hint. Setting text to `""` or `"@null"` is not sufficient because the Toast style box appears emtpy.

How can I remove that hint?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Seems that you should probably just not give that item a title (probably from xml, omit the attribute): http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10946529/actionbarsherlock-long-click-on-action-item-show-a-toast

Comment: I would like to remove that Item completely.

Comment: @A--C this answer is apparently not working (anymore?) http://stackoverflow.com/a/10955386/1018177. just tried it.

Comment: @matthias I haven't actually tried this, so I can't be sure. If you're *sure* (make the simplest test case you can) it isn't working, then leave a comment Jake's answer, maybe he'll reply.